# Where can I find XFA specs or DTD/schema?

Tags: pdf, specifications, dtd, xfa

I have a hard time finding specifications or a DTD, RNG, or XSD for XFA.

- Adobe lists the "[Adobe Supplement to ISO 32000, BaseVersion 1.7, ExtensionLevel 3](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/adobe_supplement_iso32000.pdf#page=102)" on their [PDF Reference page](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/pdf/pdf_reference.html). On page 102, there is a link to the "[Adobe XML Architecture specifications](http://www.adobe.com/go/xfa_ref_24_bibliography)", however that link is dead, and [archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/2/http://www.adobe.com/go/xfa_ref_24_bibliography) did not archive it.
- There is an old [W3C Note "XFA-Template"](https://www.w3.org/1999/05/XFA/xfa-template.html), which has a [link to a DTD](http://www.xfa.com/schema/xfa-template/xfa-template.dtd), however that link is dead as well, and from [archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20000816072015/http://www.xfa.com/schema/xfa-template/xfa-template.dtd) I get the feeling it's never really been alive. (In any case, *XFA-Template* only seems to be a part of the XFA family of specifications.)
- A Google search for "[site:adobe.com xfa specifications](https://www.google.de/?q=site:adobe.com+xfa+specifications)" turns up a link to "[Introduction to XML forms architecture (XFA)](http://help.adobe.com/livedocs/acrobat_sdk/9.1/Acrobat9_1_HTMLHelp/wwhelp/wwhimpl/js/html/wwhelp.htm?href=JS_Dev_AcrobatForms.76.48.html)". However, there is a DNS problem for me and I can't access it:
  `$ traceroute6 help.adobe.com
  traceroute: unknown host help.adobe.com`
  Archive.org doesn't help here either.

Any hint where to find that information?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a copy of the 3.3 Spec here...

[http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.364.2157&rep=rep1&type=pdf](https://web.archive.org/web/20180727230616/http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.364.2157&rep=rep1&type=pdf)

Pages 1554-1555

> The XFA schemas are written in the language [RELAX: Next Generation
>   (RNG) which is described in RELAX-NG](https://relaxng.org/). XFA schemas are written in
>   this language rather than the more usual XML-Schema 1.0
>   because XFA allows free ordering in situations where XML-Schema cannot
>   support it.
>   ...
>   **The schemas are included as file attachments in the PDF form of this document**. If you are viewing a hard copy, obtain the PDF file from the Adobe website at http://adobe.com/go/xfa_specifications.

*note the xfa specifications link does not work, nor does goolge.com/archive.org have it cached.*

### Files in the specification

1. config.rng

   - configuration
2. connectionset.rng

   - connections to web services
3. data.rng

   - user data portion of the dataSets packet
4. dataDescription.rng

   - data description portion of the dataSets
     packet
5. localeset.rng

   - locale definitions
6. pdf.rng

   - accompanying PDF
7. sourceset.rng

   - connections to databases
8. stylesheet.rng

   - XSLT stylesheet(s) for custom transformation of data and/or the template
9. template.rng

   - template
10. xdp.rng

    - container for everything else
11. xfdf.rng

    - annotations
12. xmldsig-core-schema.rng

    - signing control

I'm not sure what your goal is but I wouldn't be investing much time in XFA. It's been removed from the PDF 2.0 specification.

Comment: I'm manipulating PDF annotations in XFDF format. The [XFDF specs](https://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/xml/xfdf_2.0.pdf) reference XFA for the content of an annotation and I want to know what the content has to look like to be valid according to the specs. Thanks for tracking that down!

Comment: Ok - You don't need the XFA Specification. Other than 3D Annotations, XFA does not support annotations at all and it absolutely does not support the annotations we think of as comments. Annotations in PDF have a fixed position on a page but XFA can flow. They are incompatible. Take a look at the FDF Specification (http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/fdf_data_exchange.pdf) instead. XFDF is just an XML(ish) version of FDF.

Comment: Right, and Free Text Annotations (be they in standard PDF, FDF or XFDF) use "Rich Text Strings" (or just ordinary XML markup in the case of XFDF) "[that conform to
the rich text conventions specified for the XML Forms Architecture (XFA) specification](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf#page=436)", as the PDF 1.7 specs say. AFAIKS, the PDF 2.0 specs aren't obtainable anywhere yet, and when they are, they will only be a [paid download](https://www.pdfa.org/working-group/pdf-competence-center/). Happy adoption by the Open Source community ;-).

Comment: Ok - Yes - you're half-right... if I can be so bold. Rich Text in XFA is far more extensive than in traditional PDF forms but you'll want to limit yourself to what can be displayed in non-XFA PDF. You can find that referenced in Section 12.7.3.4 (Rich Text Strings) of the PDF specification.